# Travel from Germany to Switzerland on an Australian Refugee Travel Document

Tags: germany, switzerland, schengen-visas

Travelling on an Australian Refugee Travel Document, I am aware that I can enter Germany visa free, but from there am I able to visit/travel to Switzerland?

Answer (score 1):

While Germany does not require a visa for those holding a refugee travel document, Switzerland does.

Verified through Timatic, the database used by the airlines for passport and visa requirements, you can enter Germany with just a refugee travel document, provided you are authorised to return to the country of issue and that the document is valid for at least 4 months when you arrive. You're allowed a maximum stay of 90 days.

For Switzerland, a visa is required for passengers holding travel documents issued to stateless persons or refugees. In practice, immigration checks are not conducted for travel within the Schengen area, going from Germany and Switzerland, but you would not have the legal right to be there. As Switzerland is not an EU member, not a Customs Union with neighboring countries, travelers do tell of random checks being conducted at land borders and railway stations.

Visitors in Switzerland are required to carry a goverment-issued ID at all times. Were you asked to present identification, a refugee travel document without the required Swiss visa would be an issue.